# Working with Umbraco Node factory in ajax webservice

Tags: asp.net, xpath, asmx, umbraco

I created an .asmx web service which i call via Ajax. i used the following code

```
Node iLike = Node.GetCurrent().Parent as Node;
       Property Subject = iLike.GetProperty("emailToAdminSubject") as Property;
       Property BodyText = iLike.GetProperty("fbEmailToAdmin") as Property;
```

but Node.GetCurrent() returning a null. is there any way to get current node in an asmx Web service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.GetCurrent() won't work in the context of a web service. (See this [forum topic](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/12685-Working-with-Node-factory-in-ajax-webservice-%28find-node-by-name%29).) You could pass the current node's Id to the web service with your ajax call and then use...

```
Node iLike = new Node(id).Parent;
```

...from there.